# Plotting time series data by grouping at an hour and day level

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe which has time stamp when a ride request is raised. The data is of time series nature. I want to plot the no.of requests raised per day over 365 days. I created a new column with all ones and tried group by operation and plot, but no luck. Can anyone please help?

```
Time Stamp                        Ride
2018-04-07 07:07:17                1
2018-04-07 07:06:12                1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can do this. First let's get the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time Stamp': ['2018-04-07 07:07:17', '2018-04-07 07:06:12'], 'Ride': [1, 1]})
df['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'])
```

You can use `groupby` with a `Grouper`, which returns a series:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time Stamp', freq='1D')).Ride.sum()

# Time Stamp
# 2018-04-07    2
# Freq: D, Name: Ride, dtype: int64
```

Or you can put the timestamp in the index and use `resample`, which returns a dataframe:

```
df.set_index('Time Stamp').resample('1D').sum()

#               Ride
# Time Stamp    
# 2018-04-07    2
```

Comment: thanks a ton.IT works. I used the grouper method. 
If I want to use the resample method, I have 3 columns other than ride, how do I select only the ride column for sum ?

Comment: Since `resample` returns a different number of rows than you had originally, you need to apply it to the object as a whole. The best way, then, is to just select the columns you need before you set the index and apply resample. So, assuming you have more columns, you select the time column and all the columns that you want resampled (in this case, 'Ride') like this: `df[['Time Stamp', 'Ride']].set_index('Time Stamp').resample('1D').sum()`